# Vectors and quantity

Tags: vectors, geometry

The magnitude of a vector quantity is a *scalar quantity* (a number) and is  always positive..

I believe That direction must be always Positive but Why magnitude of Vectors  must be always Positive (Absolute Value )

> $$(\text{magnitude of }\vec A) = A = |\vec A|$$

Comment: Because would you ever answer "*How fast did you go, sir?*" with "*Negative 70 miles per hour, officer*"?

Comment: If I was confessing to driving the wrong way on an interstate, yes....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show enough previous research effort.

Comment: Why is a vector 'always positive' and not a scalar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more of a maths than physics question you have here. Simply put it's a definition and that's that.
Consider an arbitrary vector in 3D Euclidian space:

$$\vec{a}=a_x\vec{i}+a_y\vec{j}+a_z\vec{k};$$

Where $\vec{i}, \vec{j}, \vec{k}$ are unit vectors (each orthogonal, imagine a Cartesian coordinate system) of magnitude one. The coefficients that describe your vector $a_x,a_y,a_z$ can be both negative or positive it doesn't really matter here. But they are not the magnitude. The magnitude is defined as:

$$|\vec{a}|\equiv \sqrt{(a_x)^2+(a_y)^2+(a_z)^2}.$$

I assume you should agree that for real coefficients $a_x,a_y,a_z$ there is no way the magnitude of the vector can be negative when it is defined in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

I have drawn four one dimensional vectors below.

[image]
The top two vectors, $\hat a$ and $\hat b$, are called unit vectors and have a magnitude (or "length") of $1$.
Note that these vectors are in opposite directions.

The bottom two vectors, $\vec m$ and $\vec n$, both have a magnitude (or "length") of $2$.

You will note that magnitude or the "length" of a vector has nothing to do with direction, it is just a positive number relating to the "length" of the vector.

You can think of $\vec m$ as equal to $2\, \hat a$ and $\vec n$ as equal to $2\, \hat b$.

However you could write $\vec n$ as $2 \,(-\hat a) = -2\,\hat a$.

$2$ is still the **magnitude** of $\vec n$ but $-2$ is called the **component** of $\vec n$ in the $\hat a$ direction.

Confusion can arise because you can also say that the component of $\vec n$ in the $\hat b$ direction is $2$ which is also the magnitude of $\vec n$.

Now look at a two dimensional example with unit vectors $\hat i$ and $\hat j$.

[image]

$\vec r = \vec p + \vec q = 4\,(-\hat j) + 3\, \hat i = -4 \,\hat j + 3 \hat i$

The magnitudes of $\vec p, \,\vec q$ and $\vec r$ are respectively $4, \, 3$ and $\sqrt{4^2 + 3^2} = 5$

The component of $\vec r$ in the $\hat i$ direction is $3$ and in the $\hat j$ direction is $-4$.